# Show warnings or errors when redeclaring a variable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, scope

It seems that the default behavior in XCode is to silently allow redefinition of local variables if they are declared in a deeper scope, but throw an error or warning otherwise.  For example, XCode produces an error for "Redefinition of 'var'" if it is redefined in the exact same scope:

```
- (void) doStuff
{
    NSString *var = @"Hello World";
    NSString *var = @"Goodbye";  // Error on this line
}
```

Similarly, if I have an ivar called 'var', and I try to re-declare 'var' in a local method, XCode will produce a warning for "Local declaration of 'var' hides instance variable" when I try to use it:

```
//MyClass.h
...
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *var;
}
...

//MyClass.m
...
- (void) doStuff
{
    NSString *var = @"Hello World";
    NSLog(@"%@",var);                // Warning thrown on this line
}
```

So far this is what I would expect.  However, if `var` is redefined in a deeper scope, such as an `if` block or `for` loop, XCode allows it, and the outer declaration is **silently** ignored:

```
NSString *var = @"Hello World";
if (TRUE)
{
    int var = 0;
    NSLog(@"%d",var); //prints '0', No errors or warnings
}

NSLog(@"%@",var); //prints 'Hello World'
```

Why is the last example silently allowed, but the other two are caught?  Is there some option or flag I can toggle in XCode so that an error or warning would also be created in the last example?  If XCode won't catch it for me, is there some code I could write to make sure variables are never redefined?  Or is it just my responsibility to make sure I'm not re-using my variable names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last example is behavior that Objective-C inherits from standard C. A variable's scope is determined by the bracing level. It's been that way since the earliest days for C. It's called variable shadowing, and it's actually pretty useful in ensuring that code keeps working even in the face of API changes in system libraries.

As far as why it's allowed, but the earlier examples aren't, that's a consequence of how Objective-C implements instance variables. The instance variables are essentially treated as local variables of each of the class's methods. So when you declare a local variable in a function that shadows an instance variable, it gets flagged as an error. Basically the first and second cases are treated as equivalent.

To get a warning for these cases, set the LLVM warning option **Hidden Local variables** to **Yes**.

Comment: Yep, `Hidden Local Variables` is what I was looking for.  Thanks for the background info too, makes a little more sense now I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

In the build settings (Xcode 5 & 6, at least) you can set a warning for Hidden Local Variables to YES.

Comment: AHA!  Brilliant!  I was hoping this was an option somewhere, but I had no idea where to look for it.  Thanks.